# how to create a set in terraform

Tags: set, terraform, terraform-template-file

I am trying to create a set to use as an argument in the setproduct function in terraform. When I try:

```
toset([a,b,c])
```

I get an error saying I can't convert a tuple to a list. I've tried various things like using `tolist` and `...` and just having one pair of `()` braces in various places but I still can't get this to work - would anyone know how I can create a set from a,b and c?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`set` must have elements of the **same type**. Thus it can be:

```
# set of strings
toset(["a", "b", "c"])

# set of numbers
toset([1, 2, 3])

# set of lists
toset([["b"], ["c", 4], [3,3]])
```

You **can't mix types**, so the error you are getting is because your are mixing types, e.g. list and number

```
# will not work because different types
toset([["b"], ["c", 4], 3])
```